# Struggling with MySQL and Netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I need help implementing a MySQL database into Netbeans.

Basically, I've got two databases - one called Words, with 5,014 different words in and one called definitions with all the words definitions in.

I have implemented the Words database into a drop down list in NetBeans so that it presents all 5,014 words but I'm stumped as how to implement the other database so that when the user clicks, say for example, "Abandon" and the Submit button the resulting definition page will only display the definition for Abandon, which I have in the Definition database.

Here's my code for the opening page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Online English Dictionary</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 align="center">Hello and welcome to my Online English Dictionary</h1>
        <table align="center"> 
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>This Online English Dictionary uses a 5,000 word list
                        compiled by Professor Mark Davies of Brigham Young University
                        in Provo, Utah.</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>To view a definition of a particular word, please select
                        from the list below.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <form action="submit.jsp">
                            <strong>Select a word:</strong>
                            <select name="word_id">
                                <c:forEach var="row" items="${words.rowsByIndex}">
                                    <option><c:out value="${row[1]}"/></option>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </select>
                            <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

While this is the code to create my Definition database:

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Definition; 
CREATE TABLE Definition (
definition_id SMALLINT, 
definition VARCHAR (2500),
word_id VARCHAR (17),
PRIMARY KEY (definition_id),
FOREIGN KEY (word_id) REFERENCES Words(word_id)
);

INSERT INTO Definition (definition)
                    VALUES      ('1.  The first letter of the modern English alphabet.

2.  Any of the speech sounds represented by the letter a.

3.  The first in a series.

4.  Something shaped like the letter A.

5.  A The best or highest in quality or rank: grade A milk.

6.  Music 
            a.  The sixth tone in the scale of C major or the first tone in the relative minor scale.

            b.  A key or scale in which A is the tonic.

            c.  A written or printed note representing this tone.

            d.  A string, key, or pipe tuned to the pitch of this tone.

7.  A One of the four major blood groups in the ABO system. Individuals with this blood group have the A antigen on the surface of their red blood cells, and the anti-B antibody in their blood serum.'),

('vb (tr) 
1. to forsake completely; desert; leave behind: to abandon a baby; drivers had to abandon their cars. 

2.  (Nautical Terms) abandon ship the order given to the crew of a ship that is about to sink to take to the lifeboats

3. to give up completely: to abandon a habit; to abandon hope. 

4. to yield control of or concern in; relinquish: to abandon office. 

5. to give up (something begun) before completion: to abandon a job; the game was abandoned. 

6. to surrender (oneself) to emotion without restraint

7.  (Insurance) to give (insured property that has suffered partial loss or damage) to the insurers in order that a claim for a total loss may be made

n
8. freedom from inhibitions, restraint, concern, or worry: she danced with abandon.');
```

If anyone can help it would be great!

Thanks,
James

Comment: Can you provide the controller/servlet code and configurations you have setup JNDI / otherwise for connecting to the database and how you are populating the ${words} value please.

Comment: @Gyanpriya Sorry I left that bit out, I did an SQL query in NetBeans for that.
`<sql:query var="words" dataSource="jdbc/onlinedictionary">
    SELECT word_id, words FROM Words
</sql:query>`

Answer (score 0):

Well you would need to set that to the session and then in `submit.jsp` read this value and then fire another query.

That being said, I would like to recommend not to use `jstl` tags for SQL queries and use an MVC model instead where this can be easily taken care of.

Setting up the values in the controller and returning to the jsp.
onChange of the dropdown - fire an ajax request to get the details.
Show the details then and there in a separate div without navigating to other pages.

If you would still like to continue with `jstl` [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_database_access.htm) is a great tutorial if you have some time.

For MVC with JSP, you can check out couple of tutorial links :  [here](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/08/11/mvc-architecture-with-servlets-and-jsp/) and [here](http://www.java-programming.info/tutorial/pdf/csajsp2/14-MVC.pdf).

HTH.